# Can methods be treated as regular subroutines?

Tags: raku, subroutine

Is it possible to assign methods to variables and pass them around as arguments inside the class similar to subroutines?

I know they're are accessible by either `self.` or `self!` (or whatever named explicit invocant) inside other methods but I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a method's code object as an argument to another method.

Comment: `perl6 -e 'class Foo { method bar($a) { say $a } }; my &foosub = -> |c { Foo.^find_method("bar").(Foo, |c) }; &foosub(42)'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you considered passing names of methods around?

```
class Foo {
    method bar($a) { dd $a }
}
my $name = "bar";
Foo."$name"(42);  # 42
```

The syntax calls for the need of stringifications **and** parentheses to indicate you want to call that method.  If you really want to use the `Method` object and pass that around, you can, but there is no real nice syntax for it:

```
class Foo {
    method bar($a) { dd $a }
}
constant &B = Foo.^find_method("bar");
B(Foo, 42)  # 42
```

In this example, the constant `&B` is created at compile time.  But you can also call this method at runtime, e.g. when the name of the method is in a variable:

```
my $name = "bar";
my $method = Foo.^find_method($name);
$method(Foo, 42);
```

However, in that case, you would probably be better of with the `."$name"()` syntax.  See https://docs.raku.org/routine/find_method for a bit more info.

Comment: The `."$name"()` is precisely what I was looking for. BTW, for other people come across it, it also works with object instances, e.g., `class Foo { method bar($a) { dd $a } }; my $name = "bar"; say Foo.new."$name"(42);  # 42`. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There are two general mechanisms for getting ahold of a method as a [first class citizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) (something that can be passed around as an argument), depending on whether a method is [`has`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/has) scoped (almost all of them are) or `my` scoped.

## `.^find_method...` to find a `has` scoped method

The vast majority of methods are held in classes and declared without an explicit scope declarator. These are all (implicitly) `has` scoped to the class containing them.

To pass a `has` scoped method around as an argument, you need to *find* it. The *find* operation must be initiated relative to some class that either contains that method or inherits from a class that contains it. This is true even if you know the method is in the very class from which you are initiating the *find* operation. There are three options:

- [`.^find_method`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/find_method), as noted by ugexe++, is the usual tool. As you might expect, it searches inherited classes in [Method Resolution Order](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#Inheritance), starting with the class of the `.^find_method` invocant.
- On rare occasions you might want to use [`.^find_method_qualified`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/find_method_qualified) instead. This starts the search higher up the MRO than the invocant's class.
- There's one more method I'll include for completeness: [`.^lookup`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/lookup). But read the caveats in the doc. You almost certainly should NOT use this method, especially if what you wish to do is *call* the method. Use one of the `.^find_method...` methods instead.

So:

```
.has-way given class {
  method has-way { my $m = self.^find_method: 'm'; self.m-as-arg: $m }
  method m-as-arg ($m) { say self.$m } # has way
  method m { 'has way' }
}
```

## `&foo` to refer to a `my` scoped method

A few methods are not `has` scoped but are instead declared with `my`.

For these *lexical* methods, the mechanism for passing them around as arguments is to simply refer to them with a prefix `&` sigil, just as you do for `sub`s.

So:

```
.my-way given class {
  method my-way { self.m-as-arg: &m }
  method m-as-arg ($m) { say self.$m }     # my way
  my method m { 'my way' }
}
```

Comment: It's also probably not a bad idea to remind why **self**.$m is necessary: methods have an invocant, so just calling `$m` won't necessarily work as someone might think it would.  (I mention this more for beginners who may see this question and not fully grasp the sub/method distinction that can not totally obvious with `&` sigiled variables that more often contain blocks that are more sub-like).